# self reference entity model in wcf service

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight, wcf-data-services, data-modeling

I created WCF service that returned a collection of product entities from an entity frame work model .that product has self-reference .I consume data from WCF service in silverlight application .
i use Asynchronous methods . product entity was modeled this form of:

```
Public partial class Product
{

    Public  Product(){
        this.product_11=new HashSet<Product>;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> subPro{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    Public virtual Icollection<Product> product_11{get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    Public virtual Product product_12{get; set;}
}
```

and i use that in service methode

```
productEntity ef=new productEntity();

[OperationContract]
Public IEnumerable<Product> Getproduct()
{
    return ef.Product;
}
```

in run time whene call service methode i get Time out error

"the HTTP request has ... exceeded the allotted timeout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the usage of IQueryable as the return type in combination with WCF services.

```
[OperationContract]
Public IEnumerable<Product> Getproduct()
{
   return ef.Product.ToList();
}
```

In this case query is executed with the call of the `ToList()` method, thus the WCF has not to execute the IQueryable.

The second part is that you might run into serialization problems, when returning objects of the model from your context. Because EF injects the feature for lazy loading into your model classes by inheritance.

You should switch off lazy loading for your current context in the service method:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

This is described in this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/05/04/entity-framework-4-wcf-amp-lazy-loading-tip.aspx)

The next thing is that the serializer, which translates the model classes into XML-message has troubles with circular references. Here is an example which could lead to a problem:

```
public class A 
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public virtual B PropB { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string PropC { get; set; }
    public virtual A PropD { get; set; }
}
```

You can avoid this by using the `CyclicReferencesAware` attribute for the `OperationContract`method:

```
[OperationContract]
[CyclicReferencesAware(true)]
Public IEnumerable<Product> Getproduct()
{
    return ef.Product.ToList();
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: You could just try to return a list of newly created Products (without EF!) to check if the problem lies in the serialization of the answer.

Comment: I create a product type without EF with the same type of properties and send a list of product to client by WCF,this works. But the similar type with self relation in EF, Can not be perceived by the client ;

Comment: Did you retry my answer?

Comment: Tank you for your solution.CycleRefrencesAware Solved my problem.But WCF hasn't this Attribute and Should add three Class in this  link "chabster.blogspot.com/2008/02/wcf-cyclic-references-support.html‎"